# Delete duplicate values within single worksheet, for multiple worksheets in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 102 worksheets.  I want to cycle through each worksheet *independently* and remove duplicates *within* that worksheet (not across the workbook as a whole).

I currently have this code:

```
Sub DeleteDuplicates()
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each X In ws
        X.Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
    Next

End Sub
```

I believe it is deleting duplicates that appear anywhere in the workbook, not just within a single worksheet.  Is there a way to limit this code so that it only removes duplicates from within the specific worksheet it is operating on?

Comment: I guarantee you this is operating on X only.

Comment: The code certainly does what I would expect when I run it.  Why do you believe it is deleting duplicates across worksheets?

Comment: Ah - thank you.  I was trying to test it on my original data source and was forgetting to select only the column I was interested in.  Formula works as posted - I guess I shouldn't be so quick to assume I am incorrect.  Appreciate your responses.

Comment: use option explicit at top as well so all variables are declared and becomes clearer what objects are being used where.

Answer (score 2):

This cycles through each worksheet in your workbook. You can specify worksheets if you need to skip any by adding IF statements.

```
Public Sub DeleteDuplicates()

    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim wb as Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ws.Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: ws is declared as a Worksheet in your code so this will fail Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets   Also, mixing ThisWorkbook with ActiveWorkbook i think.

Comment: Good catch on the Active/This workbook! I made the change. Cheers